# Java Thread not executing

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to create a thread in Java and it's looks like it would work (thread is starting and if I try to write some random thinks into the code, the programm will return errors in thread-0. But for some reason, the code in the Thread is just not executing. When I put a simple system.out.printl on the beginning, it's not showing. I didn't found anything when I searched for this problem, so I hope you can help me.

Main:

```
  public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{

            SendMessages sm = new SendMessages();
            sm.start();

            System.out.println("2");

            while(true){
            }
        }
 }
```

Thread:

```
public class SendMessages extends Thread {
    public void run(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {

        System.out.println("1");
    }   
}
```

The "2" is printing, but not the "1".

Greetings

Comment: `run`does not throw exceptions and doesn't take parameters.

Comment: You usually don't want to extend `Thread`.  Instead, implement `Runnable` and pass it to the Thread constructor.

Comment: Also, don't have `while(true) {}` in your code. Add a `Thread.sleep()` inside or you'll peg the cpu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`run`does not throw exceptions and doesn't take parameters.

You have to override the good one:

```
public void run() {
}
```

You can add the `@Override` annotation to be sure that you override the good one:

```
@Override
public void run() {
}
```

Comment: Yep, 1+. Either that or use a Callable. Also always use the `@Override` annotation when attempting to override a method.

Comment: Thanks. I needed the exceptions for something I took out for this, because I didn't want to make the code here so big. But now, I'll move that into another class.

Comment: @Jeyex If you really need to throw exception, you should look for Callable rather than Runnable. Besides, you should avoid to extends Threads, but rather implement Runnable.

Answer (score 1):

You're not overriding the run() method correctly. The correct method signature for run is:
`public void run()`, with no params. If you change your SendMessages class to

```
public class SendMessages extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("1");
    }   
}
```

You should see the 1 printed. This is why the @Override annotation is useful - it tells you when the method you've written isn't actually overriding anything.